# How can I access to the FooterView of a UITableViewController with .grouped style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm trying to do a simple task, add a text to the footerViews for every section in my grouped Table View. I'm working for first time without Storyboards and maybe I'm missing something

I should mention that doing the same with a .plain style is working.

So I'm creating my UITableViewController subclass instance:

```
let settingsController = SettingsController(style: .grouped)
```

Then I'm implementing all the possible methods in reference to footerView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 11)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    header.textLabel?.text = "TEST"
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Why is entering in these methods when is setting up with .plain style but not with .grouped, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is this a typo? Your signature for `viewForFooterInSection` is not valid in Swift 3.

Comment: And where is the implementation of `heightForFooterInSection`?

Comment: Hi @rmaddy I've edited the question adding the implementation for 'heightForFooterInSection' and the 'viewForFooterInSection' corrected

Comment: OK, with those in place, does your code work now?

Comment: No, it doesn't...